# Disable Graphicx autorotate of images

Tags: includegraphics

I'm using TexStudio (MikTex/PDFLaTeX) to group a large number of jpg files with a custom command:

```
\newcommand{\addImg}[2][]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\subsubsection{#2}}{\subsubsection{#1}}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio=true,angle=0]{"#2"}
    
}
```

The issue is that, most of the time, those images are rotated landscape-style in the rendered pdf. I went through the manual, therefore tried angle=0, but that doesn't seem to affect the result. Do you know what can cause this please?

(I don't even get why some images are properly rendered as portrait and no landscape image is rotated to portrait)

Comment: There is no automatic rotation. Probably the graphics themselves are different.

Comment: After multiple tests, I figured out that you are right; Thx!; it's just that there's an "EXIF" data that accounts for rotation. I thought this would apply to the image directly. It means the problem isn't to be solved in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that my images were rotated in EXIF format (so more of a trick to be applied by the image reader than an actual rotation)
I solved it by applying that rotation to the whole folder in the following way (for Linux/Ubuntu users)

```
mogrify -auto-orient folder/*
```